# How do you make a player not bend down when you place the mouse pointer on it in C# and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container

I'm trying to make a script for the player's movements in order to make the player walk in all directions and rotate around itself, the problem is when I place the mouse pointer on the head or on the top of it the player bends down as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The script is below:

```
public float moveSpeed = 6;
 
     Rigidbody rigidbody;
     Camera viewCamera;
     Vector3 velocity;
 
     void Start()
     {
         rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         viewCamera = Camera.main;
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         Vector3 mousePos = viewCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, viewCamera.transform.position.y));
         transform.LookAt(mousePos + Vector3.up * transform.position.y);
         velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * moveSpeed;
     }
 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
     }
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Camera is not exactly looking top-down using the

```
viewCamera.transform.position.y
```

as distance is unreliable.

Instead of doing

```
transform.LookAt(mousePos + Vector3.up * transform.position.y);
```

you could simply rather do

```
mousePos.y = transform.position.y;
transform.LookAt(mousePos);
```

This erases any difference in Y and only rotates in XZ

Or instead of using `ScreenToWorldPoint` you could also rather directly raycast a [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) that is on the players height like e.g.

```
var ray = viewCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
var plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
if(pane.Raycast(ray, out var distance))
{
    var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    transform.LookAt(hitPoint);
}
```

---

In general when using physics you should not set anything via `transform` but rather go through the Rigidbody

```
rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.LookRotation(hitPoint)):
```

Comment: Thanks, it is also a little bit slow when turning left and right, how can I solve this problem?